# Redirect Back Open Restrict page after Login

Tags: php, cakephp

When i open directly any restriction page/url "http://domain.com/xyz/" like user,dashboard,myphoto,messages etc..then page obliviously redirect to login page and when i login then how can come back open page/url?

I am not getting any referral url in login page so please let me know how can do it using PHP and cakePHP?

Comment: What I get is, you are on one of the pages of the website, but when you need to login and login you redirect to the page you were before the login?

Comment: @Lenap Basically if the authentication is successful, he's looking for another redirection from the login page back to the dashboard page... It's kind of redundant though, since he was redirected from the dashboard page to the login page in the first place, but I understand the need.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user by using 
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'your controller','action'=>'Your action') 
in AppController.php

Comment: I am want to redirect previous page..Like if someone open direct url account,dashboard,message,etc then page redirect automatically on login page then how can redirect previous page from where he/she come...? Itz not about cakePHP itz about logic/concept...how can do it in programming...